# Is it possible to loop the session value in erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Below is my code in controller

```
@parent_kids = Student.where("parent_id = ?", found_user.id )
session[:parent_kids] = @parent_kids
```

In the view i tried following code but no luck:

```
<%  if(session[:parent_kids]) %>
     <% session[:parent_kids].each do |kids| %>
        <li >

       <a href="/school_users">
       <i class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
       <span class="menu-text"> <%= kids.first_name %></span></a>

       </li>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Easier way to write your condition: `Student.where(parent_id: found_user.id)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to put objects into your session, they can clutter it up in a hurry. Remember that things put into the session are fairly expensive to handle, so keep it small, lean, and only to things that are necessary. For example, serializing a numerical or string user ID is fine, but serializing an entire user model is not.

What you probably want is to use the instance variable directly. Iterating over `@parent_kids` is the best plan here.

Generally when debugging issues like this add code like:

```
<% if @parent_kids %>
   ...
<% else %>
  <p>No kids?</p>
<% end %>
```

If you get the "No kids" message it means your instance variable isn't correctly defined. If you were expecting it to be you can do some digging to find out why.

Remember there's a big difference in Ruby between "not defined" and "defined but empty".

A more formal definition would look like:

```
<% if @parent_kids.any? %>
  ...
<% else %>
  <p>No kids!</p>
<% end %>
```

The model's `where` method will *always* return something, so if you're not getting a defined value there it's because that code isn't executing.

Comment: Agreed with answer above. It's very bad idea to store complex objects in session, because they will be represented like strings and stored in user's cookies by default. So, it's better to use instance variables in such case, but if you really want to use session by some reason then store ids instead of objects itself.

Comment: @kimrgrey Yeah, that's the most serious issue. It's worth noting that cookies are the most common way they're stored, but not the only way, there's many ways to configure how that's done.